# Are triggers able to modify records locked by an approval process?

Tags: trigger, approval-process

A lookup field in a custom object needs to be updated after the record is submitted for approval and locked.

Is the trigger able to achieve this, even if the record is locked?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The answer is, it depends.

If you have your code written directly in the trigger or in a class designated `without sharing`, then the apex code can update records that are locked, regardless of the user who caused the trigger to fire. I tested by creating a trigger on Contact that updates a field on the Contact's Account. When the Account is locked, I can edit the contact record with a non admin user and the field on the Account gets updated.

If you use code in a class marked `with sharing` that is called by the trigger, then you will get an exception. If the trigger was executed by an Administrator, then the code will always run.

Comment: Interesting. Is your code straight in a trigger or in a class marked `without sharing`? I'd swear it fails when I tried some time ago `with sharing`. I actually want it to fail on the lock, saved me time spelling out a val. rule / trigger that users shouldn't change detail lines when master is in approval. They were changing lines, rollup recalc kicks in, boom, blocked. I need to retest it then :/

Comment: It was straight in a trigger. Didn't try it using with sharing. Maybe a little more testing is in order.

Comment: @eyescream I updated the answer as it does depend on how the class is marked for sharing.

Comment: Awesome. Thx for checking!

Answer (score 2):

It is if the user is ;)

If the action is initiated by System Administrator - sure. Otherwise - tough luck, exception will be thrown. It also depends if you've configured the approval process to "Administrator or current approver can edit the records".